# Почему на хостинге не подгружаются css/js файлы и не видит админку grapelli?

Tags: django

Дело в том что почему-то на хостинге не подгружаются css/js файлы хоть и на локалке всё работало как следует. Плюс не подгружается админка grappelli.

Вот как я подгружаю css и js в хтмл файлике

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="media/images/logominiature.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Homepage/style.css' %}">
<script src="{% static 'Homepage/js/stylejs.js' %}"></script>
```

вот что прописанно в файле settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_DIRS = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))]
```

а это от грапелли

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'Homepage.apps.HomepageConfig',
'grappelli',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Ну и пожалуй всё

Comment: https://djbook.ru/rel3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles.html

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Команда `py manage.py collectstatic` выдаёт ошибку

Comment: что именно пишет

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Пишет это `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/c/cr51888/newsite/public_html/Django/static'` Мне показалось странным что в settings.py у меня прописан путь так `STATIC_ROOT=/home/c/cr51888/newsite/public_html/Django/Homepage/static'` а в ошибке пишет по другому, Может мне стоит перенести папку static в путь который пишет в ошибке ?

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev Немного непонял как это работает, но когла я дублировал папку static и вставил  в тот путь который писал в ошибке, то одминка grappelli завелась, объясните пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить это в ваш корневой urls.py файл проекта:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: Нет, всё равно не подгружается

Answer (score 0):

Отредактируй `setting.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'))]` либо закомментируй, либо вообще удали, также важно понимать путь к `/static/` который использует web-сервер `nginx`. Если пути отличаются, то надо либо переписать путь в `nginx`, либо вынести `/static/` в необходимую директорию. И только потом пересобрать статику командой  `python manage.py collectstatic`.